# Too many redirects when using "www"-URL (https redirection is activ)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, https

I have a Wordpress installation. My URL is configured in Wordpress with "https://example.com". Due to the fact that I only want to provide a secure connection, all http://example.com requests automatically get redirected to the https-domain with the following code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code snippet is BEFORE the standard Wordpress snippet.
It works, but I cannot use www before "example.com". So Google Chrome gives me a "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error.

Thanks for your help. Highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Use this on your .htacess file. let me know if it work